# Adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying adjacency matrix and I have the following question:
Can an adjacency matrix have all their entries equal zero?

From what I understand it has zeros in its main diagonal and the other entries can be zero or one.

if there exists a path is 1 and 0 otherwise.

So I assume that from these definitions, it is not possible.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's the adjacency matrix of the graph with $n$ vertices whose edge-set is empty?

Comment: 'An empty graph on nodes consists of isolated nodes with no edges' so it is possible right?

Comment: If you have a graph with no edges then all the entries in adjacency matrix are zero. You might want to rewrite your question ... 1 if there is an edge ... There will be a path if there is a power of the adjacency matrix that has a non zero entry.

Comment: Wouldn't an adjacency "matrix" on a graph with zero vertices be an "empty matrix"? I think you rather want to consider the adjacency matrix of a graph with $n$ vertices and no edges.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter good point, I edited the answer.

Comment: The null graph?